# Cant edit CSS STYLE properties (grayed out & blocked) in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, styles, stylesheet

I am experiencing (havent seen before) something strange issue. When I enter a site (site in question is [RunForGithub.com](http://RunForGithub.com)) first time, and open up Chrome Inpsect console, then I can modify the css properties on the fly. However, when I refresh page (F5) i can no longer modify them:

[image]

the properties area is grayed out. BUt, this only happens with specific only one loaded (`runforgithub.com/_styles.css`) file, and not with other `.css` files. It's very annoying, any ideas?

Comment: i actually found that if you close the dev tools and open it again it gets fixed

Comment: bug with chrome

Comment: i also have this kind of issue from time to time ... they behave like the default  style that we find at then and we cannot modify "user agent stylesheet"

Comment: @mehulmpt Add this as an answer pal

Comment: Done @dKen ....:)

Comment: @mehulmpt Annnnnnnnnnd...upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing the dev tools and opening it again fixes this temporarily. Here's the official bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=796629

Answer (score 1):

This was approved as a bug and will be fixed in near future:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=796629

Comment: It's not fixed yet, is it?

Comment: Still not fixed. Drives me insane. Super annoying bug seeing a block of styles in italics and grayed out, when it was just edited a couple refreshes ago.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue past couple of days it was a CSS rule that was putting everything on the floor.

```
.myelement {
   background: black url("") center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

Yeah, you've seen this little hawful error !

```
.myelement {
   background: black center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

Just removing the url and everything went back to normal for me.

It's weird that SASS autocompile doesn't seem to be upset about this rule.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party. But I got mine fixed just by doing a hard reset on my website by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + R and everything went back to normal.