# Style Definitions in webtools which I cannot edit

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

Some style definition coming from my application (as rendered SCSS) are displayed in Chrome Webtools as **greyed out** (not crossed out, that is not what I mean) and labeled as `<style>` instead of a file name.

And, I cannot edit these definitions on the fly. I want to edit these style definitions on the fly as I usually can with other style definitions. What do I do?

[image]

[image]

Example with editable and non-editable but greyed out style defintions:

[image]

Comment: It will be helpful if you can demo it on an online editor, such as codePen.

Comment: I even don't know what makes Chrome displaying style definition like this, so how should I simulate this behavior in code pen?

Comment: You should be able to edit them. It's just that they are over ruled by some other style rule, which has priority.

Comment: I am not talking about crossing out

Comment: You are seeing it under elements ->style right?

Comment: yes, elements->style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Grayed Box

We need to consider the possibility that the question refers to the same bug discussed here: [Cant edit CSS STYLE properties (grayed out & blocked) in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912092/cant-edit-css-style-properties-grayed-out-blocked-in-chrome)

This issue occurs when the css rules come from style tags in your html.

#### Grayed specific rule

In Google Chrome web tools, when you are viewing `elements -> style`, you are focused on a certain element.

The grayed rules, are rules of parents, which are not inherited (according to CSS rules) and therefor don't affect the actual CSS properties of the element. For this reason you can't edit them while focused on that specific element.

If you do want to edit the css of that specific element, you can use the element.style. If you want to change the grayed out css properties, find that HTML element and focus on it. Then you can edit the rule.

On the top right you see  because the source of the css rules is within a style tag in your html file, not an external css file.

Comment: Thanks fot the hint to the bug, thats it!

Comment: The bug was opened 17 months ago, and is still opened. Css rules in style tags are dynamic (could be changed by your JS) so a bit different by nature to css rules coming from static css files.

Answer (score 1):

The ones that are grayed out could have an inherit value or is set by default from the parent. What you could do to edit or modify them is simple add a new line of style for the same property.

(adding the same padding property to override)

[image]

Edit: My bad, I thought you were referring to crossed-out.

Comment: Isn't overriding diplayed as crossing-out? That is not what I mean